# On the ratio $\frac{F_n}{B_n}$

Tags: limits, fibonacci-numbers, bell-numbers

One of the interesting limits that I came up with is:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{F_{n}}{B_{n}}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \left( n \in \mathbb N^+\right)$$

Where $F_n$ is the nth [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) and $B_n$ is the nth [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

---

If $n$ is a natural odd number then it can be written as $n=2k-1$ , where $k\in \mathbb N^+$, Using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) denoted $n!!=\left(2k-1\right)!!$ and the relation  [$B_{n}\ge n!!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585919/on-the-reciprocal-bell-constant)   we have:
$$0<\frac{F_{n}}{B_{n}} <\frac{F_{n}}{n!!}\sim  \frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2k-1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\cdot\frac{2^{k}\sqrt{2\pi k}\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^{k}}{\sqrt{4\pi k}\left(\frac{2k}{e}\right)^{2k}}<\frac{2\cdot2^{k}}{k^{k}}$$

Taking the limit as $k \to \infty$  and using squeeze theorem follows:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{F_{n}}{B_{n}}=0$$

Which means as $n$ gets larger,the fraction with the numerator counting  the number of ways to tile a board of size $1×n$ with squares and dominoes of size $1×1$ and $1×2$ respectively and the dinominator counting all possible partitions of a set with cardinality $n+1$ gets smaller.

The same can be done for $n$ even.
For more information refer to this  [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zjoqok8mog).

---

**Note**: I've already [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585919/on-the-reciprocal-bell-constant) that for all $k \in \mathbb N$ the relation $B_k\ge F_k$ holds, using this we conclude that:$$0<\frac{F_{n}}{B_{n}}\le1$$

---

The question is that: does there exist a more elegant way to prove this convergence?

Comment: $(3/2)^n < F_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n < 2^n$ but I think you're already using something like that.

Comment: Since both $F_n$ and $B_n$ are always positive, you don't need to give that lower bound for $F_n/B_n.$

Comment: @ kenta,then how should I use squeeze theorem?

Comment: You already know $F_n/B_n>0$

Comment: @  Kenta S , you are totally right, I will edit that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sicne $F_n\le 2^n$ and $B_n\ge n!!,$ we can say that $F_n/B_n\le 2^n/n!!.$ Since it is easily proven inductively that for large enough $n$ ($n\ge 21$), $n!!\ge 3^n,$ we have that, for large enough $n,$ $0<F_n/B_n\le 2^n/n!!\le 2^n/3^n=(2/3)^n.$ Now use Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Can you please prove the inequality?

Comment: I will prove the inequality when $n$ is even, as the odd case is exactly the same. First of all, $20!!\ge 3^20,$ as can be checked by a calculator. Now let $n>20$ be an even number, and assume the inequality for $n-2.$ We have that $n!!=n\cdot (n-2)!\ge n\cdot 3^{n-2}\ge 9\cdot 3^{n-2}=3^n.$ By induction, the inequality is proven for all even $n.$

Comment: Thanks, I just think it should be $n!!=n\cdot\left(n-2\right)!!$ instead of $n!!=n\cdot\left(n-2\right)!$